# when project deploys on jboss, i want to run some main() method separately with jboss

Tags: jboss, jar

My question is the same as like below.

### (Jboss version 5.0, in case it matters.)

I have a library in one of my web applications that needs to be configured with a machine-specific license before use. I don't want to put this library in shared/lib because at some point I may want to run multiple web applications with different versions of the library.

Right now the .jar files are stored in WEB-INF/lib. Thus, when I build the .war file and upload it to the server, the .jar file would still be the one bound to my PC. I would like to put a bash script somewhere in the webapp that Tomcat would automatically run when deploying the .war file - this script would then run the configuration script and bind the server's license file to the .jar. Is this possible? Is there a nicer way of doing what I want?

---

one thing is different. my jar should run with other process Id. that means it has to run as standalone separated by jboss. Even if this

```
        String command = "cmd /C java -jar C:\\test\\WEB-INF\\lib\\teststart.jar";
        oProcess = new ProcessBuilder(command).start();
```

works, I will be happy. that jar is runnable jar.

Do you have Any idea? Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html)?

Create a class that implements this and in the contextInitialized method (contextInitialized will run during war deployment) create a ProcessBuilder to run your bash command.